# Trying to drag and drop an Image in a ListBox throws an InvalidCastException on DragDrop.DoDragDrop()

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I have a ListBox bound to an ObservableCollection. I'm not using MVVM and am just binding in the Window's constructor.

```
this.LIstBox1.ItemsSource = this.MyObservableCollection;
```

In the ListBox SelectionChanged event, I'm casting the SelectedItem to an Image since I know I'm only populating the ListBox with Images. My test cast even shows a **System.Windows.Controls.Image** control.

[image]

<strike>But when I try to do DragDrop.DoDragDrop(), it throws that exception.</strike> I changed the code so that I'm passing the correct items to the correct parameters. The first item is the source (ListBox) and the second item is the object being dragged (Image). However, I'm still getting the same error. I guess it's expecting the dropped item to be a ListBoxItem. But it seems strange that it is trying to cast the ListBox. The arguments are correct now.

[image]
[image]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: You might have to reverse the first two params to `DoDragDrop`.  The first one is the _source_ while the second is the _data_.  So isn't that `ListBoxItem` (or just `ListBox`) followed by `Image`?

Comment: I don't use WPF myself, but I'm getting it from the MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dragdrop.dodragdrop.aspx

Comment: @DonBoitnott Thanks, Don. You're right, I got them mixed up. However, I'm still getting the same exception. I updated my post to reflect the change.

Comment: I wondered if the _source_ should be `ListBox` or `ListBoxItem`...did you try both?  I.e. change the first parameter to `lb.SelectedItem`?

Comment: @HansPassant What do you mean, Hans? ListBox most certainly does have a SelectedItem property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx

Comment: @DonBoitnott Still won't work. I used to have this working before. But the circumstances were a bit different. I was adding the items directly to the ListBox. So in the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event, doing this: Image item = (Image)this.lbClaims.SelectedItem;
                if (item != null)
                    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this.lbClaims, item, DragDropEffects.Move); worked. But now that I'm binding a List, the cast Image comes up null.

Comment: So, if you did the following now, does it not return a good `Image`? ...  `Image item = (Image)lb.SelectedItem`

Comment: @DonBoitnott In the SelectionChanged event, it works.

Comment: Then why can you not simply do that and pass `item` to `DoDragDrop` as before?  Perhaps post the actual code so I can see exactly what is happening.